# Hibernate Second Level Cache Returning Stale Data (sometimes)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, ehcache

Having trouble getting a consistent return from a query and second level cache with 
Hibernate 3.3, ehCache 2.4.7, C3P0 0.9.1.2, MySQL (confirmed query cache is off).

Inserting a new object and subsequently fetching that object will sometimes (about 1 in 4) fail to return the inserted object. I can confirm the insert is working through a direct database query.

Inserted entities are annotated as such: `@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)`

It's a findById query on the Primary key (which is a string, the username, as it's a new user creation process) that fails.

When it succeeds and all subsequent calls, the cache hits are clear, and no query fires, as expected.

There are two suspicious issues:

- `stats.getSecondLevelCacheStatistics` for the entity type shows the
  object in the cache, but a cache miss is recorded.
- A query is shown to fire after the cache miss, but it returns stale
  data (in this specific case, an empty list as the insert is not
  returned)

I'd expect the insert to make sure it gets into the cache, or even if that didn't work, a missed cache hit and then a correct query. However the failure to get the object into the cache, and subsequently, the failed query, is a vexing combination.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is not because of `FlushMode` on session you set. As you know if `FlushMode.COMMIT` or `FlushMode.MANUAL`(and manual flush is not called) is used there is a chance of getting stale object.

Comment: I should have mentioned that - I did check, it's still set to the default ( `FlushMode.AUTO` )